# How can I build a new collection which consists of elements that satisfy some condition?

Tags: scala

If I have a list like this in scala:

```
val list = List(
    Map("val1" -> 1, "val2" -> 2),
    Map("val1" -> 3, "val2" -> 4),
    Map("val1" -> 5, "val2" -> 6),
    Map("val1" -> 7, "val2" -> 8)
)
```

And I like to create another list where elements match certain condition like this:

```
val newList = list map { el /*match (el("val1") < 5) here*/ =>
    el /*if condition is met, add element to new list*/
}
```

Then result would be something like this:

```
List(
    Map("val1" -> 1, "val2" -> 2),
    Map("val1" -> 3, "val2" -> 4)
)
```

Is something like this possible and if so then how? I'd like to make this work from functional programming perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list.filter`:

```
val filteredList = list.filter(_("val1") < 5)
```

Comment: Cool! Just need to deal with the case `_.get("val1").isEmpty`